# Acesso ao json está retornando erro

Tags: javascript, json

tenho o seguinte json:

```
x = {
    "body-json": {
        "id": "1"
    }
}
```

Estou tentando acessar o id deste jeito:

```
console.log(x.body-json.id);
```

Acontece que não consigo acessar a referencia `body-json`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Javascript usa CamelCase. Tenta usar sempre a primeira letra minuscula e quando for outra palavra, coloque em maiúsculo. Exemplo : bodyJson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa usar a sintaxe segunte para acessar o seu objeto:

```
console.log(x["body-json"].id)
```

Como a expressão x.body-json.id é interpretada como `x.body - json.id` de acordo com as regras de sintaxe de JavaScript. Para acessar a variável que você deseja, você precisa usar a sintaxe que passa o nome da propriedade como uma string.

Comment: Com o `-` no nome da propriedade você não pode usar a sintaxe simples de acesso à propriedade do objeto.

Comment: Me equivoquei, funciona sim. +1